# How to detect if the user has scrolled back one view in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with a bunch of views that you can swipe back and forth between. I have a Next button that automatically scrolls the view forward. I want to keep the next button in sync with whenever I swipe forward/backwards. How can I detect if the user has swiped forward, and backwards so I can increment a counter respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution via: https://github.com/cwalcott/UIScrollView-Paging/blob/d0160aa2ad011bf47e1e2e78327ae840c3614107/README.txt

This will increment/decrement your page index when more than half of the next/previous page is displayed...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.yourPageIndex = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement UIScrollView's delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

In that method, you'll want to do some logic to see which index you are at based on the contentOffset of the UIScrollView

Comment: how can I determine that logic?

Comment: Assume your views are the same width, let's call that `viewWidth`, then just look for `index = scrollView.contentOffset.x / viewWidth`, this gives you the index, starting from 0. If you want to implement the same thing with up/down swiping, then the `.x` should become `.y`
Although, I don't quite get what you want to keep in sync. The next button could simply add the width of the view to the contentOffset, would work just the same, if you detect the ends of the scrollview so the user can't scroll past them.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "PageControl" in the documentation. There's a great sample project that deals with similar calculations which should help you.